# Example of an irrational number of this form.

Tags: irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Let $b:=\overline{0,b_{1},...}$ such that $b_{k} \in \{1,2\}$ and $b$ is irrational. Is $0,121122111222...$ a good example? Can you give me another example of number like this?

Comment: Sure, since it isn't periodic.  Switch the $1's$ and $2's$ to get another example.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this but wanted to make sure that there is not other kind of rational number like this.

Comment: rational is the same as periodic (or at least, periodic after an initial block).  All you need to do to produce an irrational the way is to ensure that your expression is never periodic.  One easy way to do that is to make sure it has arbitrarily large blocks of $1's$ or $2's$, as in your example.

Comment: There are of course also irrationals that do not have arbitrarily long blocks of 1's or 2's. For example, let $b_k=1$ if $k-\lfloor \sqrt k\rfloor $ is odd and $b_k=2$ otherwise (this has no block of length $>2$). Or recursively let $b_1=1$ and $b_k=3-b_{k-2^{\lfloor \log_2 (k-1)\rfloor}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, since that decimal expansion is not almost-periodic. Another possibility would be $0.121221222122221\ldots$.